# DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00") in java

Tags: java, decimalformat

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00"); 
double size=10.00;
BigDecimal t=new BigDecimal(size);
df.format(t);
```

When I give size=0.00 output will be like ".00".
Output should be "0.00", any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your pattern to `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");`

Comment: It wont, 0 is special character same as #, but it will show 0 if passed value does not have it. Have a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)